# If I own the rights to a third party game on a defunct console, can I republish it without the permissions of the console manufacturer?

Tags: emulation

Suppose I owned the rights to a third party game published on the NES. Could I make a ROM of it and sell the emulated version?

Comment: Ask a lawyer. This is sticky.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a law thing.

Comment: Maybe the [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the terms of the contract(s) that define the rights that you supposedly own, any contracts involved with having released the game on that and possibly other platforms and possibly laws of local jurisdiction.

For instance, the contracts involved with releasing it on the NES may include exclusivity clauses, which would likely prohibit selling an emulated version.

Ultimately, if you want a sound legal answer on a specific legal matter, your best bet is to consult with a legal expert.